# Python in databricks Finding duplicates in the files by directory

Tags: python, path, databricks, distinct

I'd like to look at a set of files in nested directory's based on a key.

When loading a dataframe I would like to add the file path to row data and look at the difference in the rows by key

example

```
df = spark.read.format('csv').options(header=True).load('/mnt/home/Archive/abc/*/*/*/*.csv')

# Using something like dropDuplicates()
dropDisDF = df.dropDuplicates(["pk_id]")
```

This will then let me know what files contain duplicate data by key when looking them them holistically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [input_file_name](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/input_file_name.html) function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name

df = (spark.read.format('csv').options(header=True)
           .load('/mnt/home/Archive/abc/*/*/*/*.csv')
           .with_column('file', input_file_name()))

dropDisDF = df.dropDuplicates(["file", "pk_id]")
```